# Plotting a list of callouts doesn't work

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, labeling

I can plot a bunch of `callout`'s without problems:

```
Plot[{Callout[Sin[x], "S"], Callout[Cos[x], "C"]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

But, if I create a variable with the list of those callouts and try to plot it, I only get a white plot:

```
p = {Callout[Sin[x], "S"], Callout[Cos[x], "C"]};
Plot[p, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated (or, in any case, thank you for reading this).

Comment: You need to use `Plot[Evaluate[p], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to my problem after reading more than 10 random posts on callout and lists... I'm sorry for posting a similar question. Also, thank you to the moderators, and specially to Carl Woll for providing the correct answer on his comment.